# Getting a timer ID within its callback in setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using TypeScript and Angular to build an app. In a component, I create a few timeouts and I want to be sure to cancel them when my component is destroyed. To do so, I have a `Set<number>` that keeps track of active timeouts. When my component is destroyed, I simply iterate over this set and cancel all my timeouts. When I create a timeout, I add its ID to the Set. My problem is that I currently don't have a way to remove the ID from the Set when the timeout has executed. I want to be able to get the timeout ID inside my callback function to remove it from the Set. Is there a way to do this?

Here is some code that could explain:

```
export class CustomComponent implements OnDestroy {
    private activeTimeouts: Set<number> = new Set<number>();

    // Method called when component is destroyed
    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.activeTimeouts.forEach((item) => {
            clearTimeout(item);
        });
    }

    someFunction() {
        const timerID = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Hello World");
            // How can I get timerID from here?
        }, 1000);
        this.activeTimeouts.add(timerID);
    }
}
```

As you can see from my code, I would like to be able to remove the `timerID` after `console.log("Hello World");` is executed. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The code inside the timer function can directly refer to `timerID`.

Comment: Did something go wrong when you tried to access `timerID` right there? I don't see any problem beyond not writing the code you want in the place you want. Was there some error?

Comment: Javascript never ceases to amaze me. I never tried to reference `timerID` because I thought it wouldn't be in the same scope or be undefined inside the callback.

Comment: All functions, including anonymous ones, are lexically scoped. They also create a closure over their original lexical environment, so that even if the function continues to exist after its original environment has exited, it can still reference those vars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed use the timerID in the scope of setTimeout.

- The function that's there within setTimeout is a **closure.**
- Closure helps when functions are probably called later on in code but need to refer to variables outside their local scope when they're called.

```js
const timerID = setTimeout(() => {
    useTimerIdentifier(timerID);
    console.log("timer accessed");
}, 3000);
```

Comment: He doesn't want to clear it when the callback executes. He wants to remove it from the `Set` that holds all the timer ids.